# Vertical 5x5 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print an output that looks like this:

```
0   5   10  15  20
1   6   11  16  21
2   7   12  17  22
3   8   13  18  23
4   9   14  19  24
```

But it just keeps coming out like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0
1   6   0   0   0
2   7   12  0   0
3   8   13  18  0
4   9   14  19  24
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][]matrix = new int[5][5];
    fillSequentialMatrix2D(matrix);
}
public static void fillSequentialMatrix2D(int [][]matrix) {
    for(int j=0, k=0; j<matrix[0].length ;j++){
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length ;i++){
            matrix[i][j] = k++;
            System.out.print("\t"+matrix[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

How do I make it print correctly?

Comment: You're printing values before you populate them.  First fill your array, then print it.

Comment: You assign `matrix[i][j]` but print `matrix[j][i]` (`i` and `j` are flipped). Suggest you create separate method for printing, so the `fill` method doesn't exactly that: Fill the matrix, without printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the above comment mentioned you need to remove the output from the loop.

```
public static void fillSequentialMatrix2D(int [][]matrix) {
    for(int j=0, k=0; j<matrix.length ;j++){
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length ;i++){
            matrix[i][j] = k++;
            //System.out.print("\t" + matrix[j][i]);
        }     
       // System.out.println();
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
            System.out.print("\t" + matrix[j][i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Sample output from above.

```
0   5   10  15  20
1   6   11  16  21
2   7   12  17  22
3   8   13  18  23
4   9   14  19  24
```

Comment: The reason why the numbers 5, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23 were not output in your result is because during the iteration output of the loop they had yet to be put into the array.

Comment: The why don't we moving row-wise Instead of going column-wise?

Comment: He wanted them output in column not row format please look at original question requirements.